# Remove SOME duplicates in data.table column X, but retain duplicates if column Y matches condition

Tags: r, data.table

Rather than keep the first row of a data.table in which the value in the column matches a condition, I would like to keep all rows in which the value in a column matches a primary condition, OR only one row if it matches a secondary condition but with priority for one value over another.

Imagine data.table `test` with two columns, `ID` and `STATUS`. Retain all rows of `test` for which `STATUS == A`, but only keep one row of ID if `STATUS == B | C`, and if `B` and `C` both occur for a given value of `ID` (but `A` does not occur), keep the first row for which `STATUS == B` and remove all rows for which `STATUS == C`.

```
library(data.table)

test = data.table(ID=sample(c(1:3),30,replace=TRUE),STATUS=sample(LETTERS[1:3],30,replace=TRUE))
#> setkey(test,ID,STATUS)
#> test
#    ID STATUS
# 1:  1      B
# 2:  1      C
# 3:  1      C
# 4:  1      C
# 5:  2      A
# 6:  2      A
# 7:  2      A
# 8:  2      A
# 9:  2      A
#10:  2      B
#11:  2      B
#12:  2      B
#13:  2      B
#14:  2      B
#15:  2      C
#16:  2      C
#17:  2      C
#18:  2      C
#19:  2      C
#20:  3      C
#21:  3      C
#22:  3      C
#23:  3      C
#24:  3      C
#25:  3      C
#26:  3      C
#27:  3      C
#28:  3      C
#29:  3      C
#30:  3      C
#    ID STATUS
```

For `ID == 1`, only keep row 1 (where `STATUS == B`).

For `ID == 2`, keep rows 5 through 9 (where `STATUS == A`), and get rid of rows 10 through 19 (where `STATUS == B | C`).

For `ID == 3`, keep one row where `STATUS == C`.

Expected output:

```
#    ID STATUS
# 1:  1      B
# 2:  2      A
# 3:  2      A
# 4:  2      A
# 5:  2      A
# 6:  2      A
# 7:  3      C
#    ID STATUS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could create an `ordered` 'STATUS' based on the `levels` 'A', 'B', 'C', grouped by 'ID', extract the `first` present `levels` (after applying `droplevels`), do a comparison with 'STATUS' to return logical vector, convert it to a numeric index (`.I`) also have a condition to check if the number of unique elements in the column is 1, return only the first row

```
test[test[, .I[if(uniqueN(STATUS) == 1) 1 else 
   STATUS == first(levels(droplevels(ordered(STATUS, 
          levels = c("A", "B", "C")))))], ID]$V1]
#   ID STATUS
#1:  1      B
#2:  2      A
#3:  2      A
#4:  2      A
#5:  2      A
#6:  2      A
#7:  3      C
```

#### data

```
test <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), STATUS = c("B", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C")), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

Comment: My real world data had almost 300,000 rows, and this did the job beautifully in 5 seconds.

Comment: @NigelStackhouse. To be more aligned with the type can wrap with `which` if you are not using `.I` ie.  `test[test[, .I[if(uniqueN(STATUS) == 1) 1L else which(STATUS == first(levels(droplevels(ordered(STATUS, levels = c("A", "B", "C"))))))], ID]$V1]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option which should be faster:

```
setkey(test, ID, STATUS)
test[STATUS=="A" | c(TRUE, diff(ID) > 0L)]
```

output:

```
   ID STATUS
1:  1      B
2:  2      A
3:  2      A
4:  2      A
5:  2      A
6:  2      A
7:  3      C
```